# How to Separate Row Values in Text View's in PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have parsed the json data in TableView. The code for table view is given below-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="pagetwo">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Cars</h1>
      <a href="levels.html" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">Back</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" style="margin-top:-20px;">
            <h2></h2>
            <ul data-role="listview" id="listid">
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function()
              {
              $.getJSON("json/details.json",function(data)
                    {
                var html="";
                for(var d in data.cars)
                    {
                for(var i in data.cars[d])
                    {
 html+= "<li><a href=''>"+data.cars[d][i].model+" <p>"+data.cars[d][i].doors+"</p></a></li>";
                    }
                    }
                    $("#listid").append(html);
                    })
              .done(function()
                    {
                    $("#listid").listview().listview("refresh");
                    });
              });
            </script>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

Now, When i click on first row, it should separate the **Indica** and Four **Doors** in Two test View, Like this-

Please give me suggestion. Thanks in Advance !!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
html+= "<li><a href=''><span>"+data.cars[d][i].model+" </span><p>"+data.cars[d][i].doors+"</p></a></li>";

$('li a').on('click', function(event){
    $('#model').text($(this).children('span').text());
    $('#door').text($(this).children('p').text());
})
```

Comment: i tried ur code, but i m getting nothing in simulator

Comment: hi, @ImranKhan first you need to add two div or textarea which two id are #model and #door in your html page, then add data.cars[d][i].model inside the span tag.

Comment: my first page is in question it self and second page is here http://pastebin.com/ZfEs27QZ. Now i want to navigate from first to second page.

Comment: above list is your first page and showing car with model and door is your second page..?

Comment: yes in first page, which is in my question,,, i m displaying data in table view.. if u see first row.. Indica and Four doors, when i click on it i want it to display on second page, that i have given u

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52155/discussion-between-imran-khan-and-ved)

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the text in a function on onClick. 
Example:

```
<a onClick="cars(carName, carDoors)"/>
function cars(name, doors){
    $('#carView').html(carName); //set the text for the car view
    $('#doorView').html(carDoors);
}
```

Comment: hi could u explain me here car view and door view